# ограничение регистрации по домену в почте

Tags: python

Есть фрагмент файла с настройками

```
"REGISTRATION_EMAIL_PATTERNS_ALLOWED": [
    "^.*@(.*\\.)?gmail\\.com$",
    "^.*@(.*\\.)?ukr\\.net$",
    "^.*@(.*\\.)?bigmir\\.net$",
    "^.*@(.*\\.)?(.*\\.)?\\.ua$"
],
```

Ошибка в последней строке, нужно разрешить все домены @*.ua подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: @Иван-Пшеницын
благодарю, заработало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить на

```
"^.*@(.*?)\\.ua$"
```